# How to get off two loops by using goto and run statements after loop?

Tags: c, goto

I need ideas to try to make this program more readable. I think that it's more a question about designer than other.

I have two loops:

```
for( ... ) {
  //... 
   for(...) {
     if(baa) {
       goto outer;
      } 
      //statements of 2-loop
    }
     //statements of 1-loop
}
```

it works fine, if `baa` has non-zero value, jump to `outer` label without run stataments of loop 1 and 2. But before `return`, I need to do some `free()` calls independent if `goto outer` was called:

```
 if(a != NULL) free(a);
 if(b != NULL) free(b);
```

but if I'm here because `goto`, the above code isn't called.

And I need do the following:

```
   goto outer; //if normally exited from two-loops, go to outer anyway.

    outer: {
     if(a != NULL) free(a);
     if(b != NULL) free(b);
        return ret;
    }
```

What makes the function something like this:

```
char* foo(void) {
  char *ret = NULL;

  for( ... ) {
    //... 
    for(...) {
     if(baa) {
        ret = tmp_result;
        goto outer;
      } 

       //some statements of 2-loop
     }
       //some statements of 1-loop
    }

  goto outer;

  outer: {
     if(a != NULL) free(a);
     if(b != NULL) free(b);
         return ret;
  }
}
```

I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need the `goto outer;` outside the loops, the `outer:`-labelled statement is executed anyway after exiting the loops.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Really. I had forget of it! Thanks very much. Post it as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `outer` label is ignored by the normal control flow, it's only used as the target of the `goto`, so you don't need it after the loop. Further, there is no need to group the statements after the label into a compound statement,

```
char* foo(void) {
  char *ret = NULL;

  for( ... ) {
    //... 
    for(...) {
     if(baa) {
        ret = tmp_result;
        goto outer;
      } 

       //some statements of 2-loop
     }
       //some statements of 1-loop
    }

  outer:
     if(a != NULL) free(a);
     if(b != NULL) free(b);
     return ret;
}
```

does exactly the same (and is IMO a bit nicer on the eyes).